# inserting multiple row in sql using subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I want to insert multiple row using one insert sql query. I know it is possible to insert multiple row in one sql query.

I have written some query as
  `insert into test values ((select loan_id from loan_transaction_mcg))`

but I received the error
`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Is there anyway to insert data like this way. I have single column in `test` table.

Comment: Note that the [manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174335.aspx "INSERT (Transact-SQL)") mentions the corresponding syntax (`INSERT ... SELECT`) and has [examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174335.aspx#OtherTables "INSERT (Transact-SQL): Inserting Data from Other Tables") too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your test table is already created and contains only a `loan_id`, all you have to do is drop `values` and remove the now redundant parentheses.

```
INSERT INTO test SELECT loan_id FROM loan_transaction_mcg
```

Comment: why i have to remove parenthesis. i am confused on this.

Comment: @Dinupkandel - You don't actually *have* to but they *are* redundant. I'll edit the answer to better reflect that.